# Android - Retrieve the state of WebView

Tags: android, dictionary, webview

I have a `WebView` which displays a map. I have the default `mUrl` which sets the map to a specific location with a specific zoom. When I push another `Fragment` and then go back to my `MapWebFragment` my `onCreateView` gets called and loads the default `mUrl` instead of letting the `WebView` state be like it was before (another zoom and location) when I pushed the new `Fragment`.

I followed a turoial to save the state of `WebView` but it didn't work.

My code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_web, container, false);

    webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());


    if(webViewBundle != null){
        webView.restoreState(webViewBundle);
    } else {
        webView.loadUrl(mUrl);
    }

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    webViewBundle = new Bundle();
    webView.saveState(webViewBundle);
}
```

Comment: Be sure you are loading the url again...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save state to your own created bundle.

webViewBundle is class member. But what happens entire instance is replaced (old fragment instance is abandoned, then new instance is created) so the reference would be lost as well.

to store state you have to save state into the bundle provided as param in

```
onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outbundle)
```

then the same bundle will be passed as savedInstanceState in

```
 onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

and other lifecycle methods, so use it to recover state

NOTE:
Normally fragments take care of restoring all views that have ID or TAG assigned (manually or from xml) automatically.